# How do I align the rotation of this star to the face closest to it without it phasing through?

Tags: mesh

[image: Star]

How do I align the rotation of this star to the face closest to it without it phasing through?
[The closest that I've gotten it to working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdyEg.png) + [My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYZBV.png)

***P.S.** I thought making the surface flat could make it easier*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instinct to create a reference plane is a good one. You could do it that way.

Unless you want to move the object-origin of your star-object with respect to its mesh, though, there's always going to have to be some sort of parenting to a proxy origin in the right place with the correct orientation, so let's do it without creating extra geometry.

[image]

With Transform Orientation set to 'Local', working in Object Mode, throughout...

- Create an Empty. Arrows will help you see what you're doing.
- Set Snap to 'Vertex', with 'Align Rotation' **on**, and snap the Empty to an inner vertex.

[image]

- Z is pointing the wrong way.. <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>180</kbd> rotate the Empty so Z is inwards.
- In the snap, set 'Align Rotation' **off**, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> snap the Empty to one of the star's adjacent point-vertices (in its local Z, only).

With both selected, and the Empty active, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> parent the star to the Empty. Now we're kitted up, with Snap set to 'Face' and 'Align Rotation' **on** again, to snap the Empty to faces around the scene, with the star following:

[image]

At any time, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, clear the star's parenting, with 'Keep Transformation', and you're set.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my snapping? Where yours was inward, mine was out.

Comment: It did work though, I just had to skip over flipping the Empty.

Comment: @grem great! So long as you're on board with the general idea.,, maybe your surface is inside-out? If the normals are pointing the other  way...